# ubuntu phone alcatel pixi3(4.5)

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a alcatel pixi 3 (4.5) 5017x.

I would love ubuntu phone on it,

but that fails me,

I really tried everything,

Please help my,

grt gunter

Comment: Ubuntu Phone only runs on specific phones designed for it. I don't think the Pixi3 is a Ubuntu phone.

Comment: Ubuntu does not run on Android phones.

Comment: there are there where it has succeeded

Comment: It won't work on very many phones. You should buy one with Ubuntu already.